# How to make a POST request to Stripe endpoint without CORS preflight

Tags: node.js, http, cors, stripe-payments

Trying to make a basic POST request to Stripe endpoint in Node:

```
const https = require('https');
const options = {
  hostname: 'connect.stripe.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/oauth/token',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
  }
}

const req = https.request(
  options, res => 
    res.on('data', d => 
      process.stdout.write(d))
)
req.write(data) // client_secret=stripe_sk&grant_type=authorization_code...
req.end()
```

#### The response

```
Failed to load https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 400.  If an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

#### server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const nextI18NextMiddleware = require('next-i18next/middleware');
const nextI18next = require('./i18n');
const app = next({ dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' });
const routes = require('./routes');
const handler = routes.getRequestHandler(app);

(async () => {
    await app.prepare();
    const server = express();
    nextI18NextMiddleware(nextI18next, app, server);
    server.get('*', (req, res) => handler(req, res));
    await server.listen(3000);
    console.log('Ready on http://localhost:3000');
})();
```

#### Wild guess

Looks like something's silently modifying the headers and it's not a *simple* POST but a POST with some additional headers which, in it turn, trigger a `CORS preflight` rules.
Using Postman I get expected results and the problem is in headers.

How can I learn what's affecting my POST requests?
Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

## HTTP 303

```
Request URL: https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 303 
Remote Address: 54.187.119.242:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: 
location: https://connect.stripe.com/login?redirect=%2Foauth%2Ftoken
referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
request-id: 1550537522-mreq_9XV0Kp3XVIJYPq
server: nginx
status: 303
strict-transport-security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-ua-compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Provisional headers are shown
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
```

## OPTIONS request

```
Request URL: https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 303 
Remote Address: 54.187.119.242:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: default-src 
location: https://connect.stripe.com/login?redirect=%2Foauth%2Ftoken
referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
request-id: 1550537522-mreq_9XV0Kp3XVIJYPq
server: nginx
status: 303
strict-transport-security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-ua-compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-headers
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
DNT: 1
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/profile/edit?code=ac_EYThaA5LNla8&state=35N1UGuPHac9
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Use the Network pane in browser devtools to examine the preflight OPTIONS request. Look at the value of the Access-Control-Request-Headers request header. That will tell you what headers are triggering the browser to make the OPTIONS request. Then figure out what part of your frontend code is causing any header to be added.

Comment: That means somewhere in your frontend code, you have code that’s trying to add an 'access-control-allow-headers' request header to the request. Either that or maybe you have a browser extension that’s adding it. Either way, it’s wrong, because access-control-allow-headers is a response header, not a request header. It should never be sent in requests.

Comment: This error almost always happens if you do the request client-side. You can not do that request client-side as it uses your Secret API key and it has to be done server-side

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The request would come from your code server-side and you would not run it in a browser.

Comment: When it comes to dealing with the Stripe API, your frontend should do one thing and one thing only: tokenization. All other Stripe actions need to be performed on your backend as they require your Stripe secret key. 

Since you're in node, you'll make your life a lot simpler if you use the official Stripe node bindings: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node

Comment: This was actually added recently to the stripe-node library, although it looks like the documentation hasn't quite caught up yet. Here's an example on how to use it: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/test/resources/OAuth.spec.js#L65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`

For Firebase Cloud Functions you would do this...

```
res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
res.status(204).send('');
}
```

However, I'm not sure which server you're using, so I can't give you the exact code.

Comment: Don't know who has downvoted this answer though. All I could find at the internet is the recommendation to set the Origin: *. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that server. I wish I could be of more help.